# HTML font weird behavior in Firefox

Tags: firefox, webfonts

I have noticed this weird behavior in firefox, it seems like font have some colorful noise. The example is shown in the image.

[image: Difference between firefox and other browsers]

Does anyone know how this can be solved? With some CSS media type (which now is screen)?

I'm using firefox 4.0.1.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like font smoothing to me.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a reset-css. Is this a reset-css causing this? Reset-css is used only to reset margins and paddings of misc html elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing subpixel font positioning and rendering.  I assume that you're on Windows, which is why you only see it with Firefox 4 (and IE9, if you try that).  On Mac, Firefox has done this for a very long time.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7, ClearType doesn't solve this rendering problem? Is there any way to make font look better in Firefox?

Comment: ClearType is what _causes_ the problem, effectively.

Comment: Please note that in FireFox this will also happen with WOFF and WOFF2 fonts whenever ClearType is on.  The effective solution is to use TTF for FireFox.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311697/wrong-rendering-of-google-fonts-in-mozilla-firefox/33792996#33792996